# Send Entire DOM through Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, ajax, bookmarklet

I have a site where I save URLs and I want to process and save the entire DOM (in case the site goes down -- I'll still have access to the content).

The current version of my javascript bookmarklet (which only saves the URL and Page title) has been submitting a series of GET variables to a PHP page. However this will not work for the entire DOM because there are URL limit constrictions (usually ~15,000 characters it seems).

I think that using POST would allow me to send more information but I believe that the browser will stop it because of XSS (cross site scripting) concerns.

Is there a way to send a large amount of data (15,000char+) from a javascript bookmarklet?

I'm happy to clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a form(in an iframe) -> set its values -> submit -> remove the iframe.

the reason for the iframe is so the page doesnt navigate away when you submit the form.

there wont be any permission issues.

Comment: Chris - how do I get the values into the form is the form is being called in from an external iframe? I am using an iframe right now but am loading it by submitting Get variables to it. Thanks!!

Comment: Clarification: so you create a form, fill it's values, then POST that form to the iframe you have also created on the same page?

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195396/sending-text-cross-domain-by-bookmarklet?